# Does providing an explicit deduction guide disable the generation/formation of implicit deduction guides

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, ctad, deduction-guide

I am reading about [deduction guides](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.guide) in C++17. So say we have the following example:

```
template<typename T> struct Custom 
{
  
};
template<typename T> struct Person 
{
    Person(Custom<T> const&);
    Person(Custom<T>&&);
};
template<typename T> Person(Custom<T>) -> Person<T>; //explicitly declared deduction guide
```

My question is that will the explicit declaration for the explicit deduction guide(as shown above) **disable** the formation of the 2 implicit deduction guides(corresponding to the 2 ctors of class template `Person`) that would have been there if we did not specify an explicit deduction guide. I mean, suppose in the above example, there was no explicit deduction guide, then there will be 2 implicit deduction guides(corresponding to the two constructors of `Person`). But after we have added explicit guide, will we have a total of 1 deduction guide(explicitly declared by us the user) or 3 deduction guides(including 2 implicit deduction guides).

PS: Note that the question is only about the deduction guides for `Person` and not about whether implicit guide will be formed for `Custom`.

Answer (score 8):

No, *deduction-guide* declarations do not suppress the formation of implicit deduction guides during the class template argument deduction process. The overload set will contain both. See [[over.match.class.deduct]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1):

> ... a set of functions and function templates, called the guides of `C`, is formed comprising:
>
> - If `C` is defined, for each constructor of `C`, a function template with the following properties: ...
> - If `C` is not defined or does not declare any constructors, an additional function template derived as above from a hypothetical constructor `C()`.
> - An additional function template derived as above from a hypothetical constructor `C(C)`, called the *copy deduction candidate*.
> - For each deduction-guide, a function or function template with the following properties:  ...
>
> [additional provisions related to aggregates omitted...]

However, the third last tiebreaker in the overload resolution process gives precedence to *deduction-guides* (*i.e.*, explicitly declared deduction guides) over implicit deduction guides. [[over.match.best.general]/2.10](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.10). This tiebreaker is only reached after all of the more general tiebreakers (not related directly to deduction guides) are tried.

Comment: @AnoopRana If you want to see the numbering, you can click on the links. I am only summarizing the parts that are directly relevant to the answer and I believe that adding numbering to the bullet points will add clutter instead of making the answer easier to read.

Comment: So does this means that for class template `Person` we will still have 3 deduction guides in total? One explicitly deduction guide and two corresponding to the ctors of `Person`. Also note that my question is only about the deduction guides for `Person` and not about whether implicit guide will be formed for `Custom`.

Comment: I see 2 problems with this answer. 1) Formatting is too bad(which is specific to me). 2) The answer does not clearly answer my question. In particular, i specifically asked will we have 1 or 3 deduction guides for `Person` or maybe more if i am wrong.  I recommend updating it accordingly.

Comment: @AnoopRana The number of deduction guides for `Person` is a corollary of what is stated in the answer. The first bullet point contributes 2 deduction guides, the third contributes 1, and the fourth contributes 1.

Comment: Ok, this comment is what is needed(should be added IMO to) in the answer to make the answer more clear and complete.

Comment: @AnoopRana I disagree that it needs to be added to the answer. Like I said, it is a corollary of what is already stated.

Comment: It's  fine if you don't want to be explicit. I was only suggesting an edition to the answer that would make it more clear. Anyways i got my answer(through the comment that you made). Thanks for the effort and clarification.